# Wie sagt man "Please wait in a queue" auf Deutsch?

Tags: phrase

Was könnte man auf ein Schild vor einer Kasse schreiben, das die Kunden auffordert eine Warteschlange zu bilden/in der Warteschlange zu warten, wenn es schon jemanden gibt, der an der Kasse bedient wird?

Ich dachte an

> Bitte warten Sie in der Warteschlange

oder

> Bitte stellen Sie sich in der Warteschlange an

aber ich konnte diese Satze nicht im Internet finden (darum denke ich, dass sie falsch sind). In den Wörterbüchern fand ich auch kein Beispiel, obwohl ich dachte, dass es eine populäre Phrase wäre.

Comment: Probiere "Schlange" ohne "Warte-"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich habe noch nirgends einen Hinweis gesehen, dass man bitte eine Schlange bilden möge. Was ich aber mehrfach gesehen habe (zum Beispiel gestern am Bahnhof München-Pasing in einer Bäckerei) war der Hinweis:

> Bitte hier anstellen.

Der ist natürlich schon in gewissem Sinne listig, denn er ermahnt die Wartenden *nicht* einfach dazu, eine Schlange zu bilden. Vielmehr setzt er bereits voraus, dass eine Schlange zu bilden sei, und setzt lediglich den Beginn der Schlange fest.

Comment: In Banken u.ä. reicht auch häufig eine Linie auf dem Boden, mglw. mit dem Hinweis „Diskretion bitte!“ o.ä. Auch anderswo dienen eher Absperrungen aller Art dem Zweck – nicht Schilder, allenfalls welche mit Richtungspfeilen.

Comment: Gewissermaßen stimme ich zu - aber ich sehe daran nichts *Listiges*. Ganz im Gegenteil, sowohl Höflichkeit als auch Effizienz gebieten eigentlich ohnehin das Bilden einer Schlange. Ich fände eher die Ermahnung, eine Schlange zu bilden, listig, geht sie doch davon aus, dass es den Wartenden an dieser grundlegenden Sozialkompetenz fehlt. Die Hauptinformation von "Bitte hier anstellen." ist in der Tat der Startpunkt der Schlange, damit sich nicht an verschiedenen Seiten konkurrierende Schlangen bilden bzw. damit sich eine etwaige Schlange nicht in eine ungeschickte Richtung entwickelt.

Comment: @Crissov: *Diskretion bitte!* sagt aber eigentlich nicht, dass man eine Schlange bilden solle, sondern zunächst einmal, wo man nicht hingehen sollte (egal, ob beim Anstellen, oder um sich einen Flyer vom Schalter zu holen), wenn gerade ein anderer Kunde beraten wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die direkte Ermahnung, eine Schlange zu bilden, finde ich eher *anmaßend* oder *unterstellend* denn *listig.* Wie du schon sagst, ginge sie davon aus, dass diese Höflichkeitsgrundkompetenz fehle – was implizit auch etwas über das Denken des Aufhängenden über die Wartenden aussagt (»Sie können es nicht«). Die List bei »Bitte hier anstellen« ist meines Erachtens, dass der Wartende davon ausgehen kann »Aha, der vertraut mir« während sich der Schreibende gedacht haben kann »Und falls er es nicht gemacht hätte, ist er hiermit nochmal an die Schlange erinnert.«

Comment: Er sagt also quasi etwas anderes, als das, was er eigentlich meint; dabei erlaubt es allen Beteiligten, das Gesicht zu wahren. Übrigens ist *listig* durchaus ein anerkenndes Wort.

Answer (score 5):

Das kann man schon so sagen:

> Bitte warten Sie in der Warteschlange

Üblich wäre wahrscheinlich auch, je nach Kontext:

> Bitte stellen Sie sich hinten an.

Comment: Letzteres wird aber eher verwendet, wenn jemand nicht merkt, dass es eine Schlange (oder zumindest eine Reihenfolge) gibt.

Comment: Ja, das stimmt - es ist kontextabhängig.

Answer (score 2):

Stellt man an einer Kasse fest, dass sich die Leute ungeordnet aufstellen, kann man sie mit folgender Aufschrift »umerziehen«:

> Bitte eine Schlange bilden!

Oder in Kurzform:

> Bitte Schlange bilden!

Answer (score 0):

"Warteschlange" ist zwar korrekt, aber der meistgehörte Ausspruch ist jedoch:

> Bitte in einer Reihe anstellen.